# Normalise levels, contrast, brightness of an image sequence

Tags: images, ffmpeg, conversion, imagemagick, mogrify

When making animated gifs or short stop-motion videos from an image sequence, I want them to have all similar levels so that the output looks smooth.  It does not have to be a professional quality result, just a simple command to adjust for the different photographs having slightly different exposure variables which causes flickering in the animation.

So, I'm looking for a simple command line way to make a sequence of images normalised to approximately similar levels.

Comment: Please specify your operating system and version.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: There IS a normalize function in imagemagick (and also graphicsmagick). Whether it will give you desirable results is difficult to say. However, do have a look at [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23545) discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Choose one of the images that has good levels.  Use the imagemagick script [histmatch](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php) to adjust the histograms of the other images to match that one's;  or use [bcmatch](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/bcmatch/index.php) to adjust only brightness and contrast.

Call e.g. `histmatch good_in.bmp ith_in.bmp ith_out.bmp` from within a loop, in whatever language you like: bash, perl, python, ruby, etc.